# A group with a prime number of elements with prime order?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $p$ is a prime number, show that there is no group with $p$ elements of order $p$.

Comment: I think it meant there exist exactly $p$ elements $g$ such that $g^p=1$.

Comment: For $p=2$, and an *infinite* group $G$, it takes a little more work to show that there cannot be exactly $2$ elements of order $2$, since the easy "pairing" argument breaks down.

Comment: I think the wording is ambiguous.  I first read it as there is no group with p elements in which the order of the group is p.  Which is of course not true at all.  It was only after reading it three times are realized it meant there is no group that has p elements of order p.

Comment: This would help with $p=2$: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/No_Group_has_Two_Order_2_Elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is an odd prime. If $G$ is a group and $x \in G$ has order $p$, then the $p-1$ distinct elements $x, x^2, \ldots, x^{p-1}$ each have order $p$ (why?). Thus, $p-1$ divides the number of elements of $G$ of order $p$.

What about the case $p=2$?

Comment: Because the subgroup created by $x$ ($<x>$) is cyclic, therefore all of $<x>$ subgroups are cyclic, and we know that each such subgroup of it has order that divides $p$, therefore each element in $<x>$ must have order $p$ since $p$ is prime except for $e$. Correct? But I didn't understand why that means sthat $p-1$ divides the number of elements of $G$ of order $p$.

Comment: You also have to argue that the sets of the form $\{x,x^2,\dots,x^{p-1}\}$ are either equal or disjoint for different values of $x$.

Comment: @TheNotMe Correct. If $A$ is the set of elements of $G$ of order $p$, then $A$ can be partitioned into disjoint sets of the form $\{x, x^2, \ldots, x^{p-1}\}$ (this needs proof also). Thus $p-1$ divides the size of $A$.

Comment: I still do not get why $p-1$ divides the number of elements of $G$ of order $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that the number of elements of order $p$ is divisible by $p-1$ (hence even for odd $p$). Then the case $p=2$ is the only exceptional case, and can be dealt with separately.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $G$ is a group, whose order is divisible by a prime $p$, then $\#\{x \in G : \text { order}(x)=p\} \equiv -1$ mod $p$. This follows easily from the proof of McKay of Cauchy's Theorem, see [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/McKay%20Another%20Proof%20of%20Cauchy%27s%20Group%20Theorem.pdf). Hence in your case, $p \equiv -1$ mod $p$, implying $p \mid p+1$, which is absurd.